# Dimension of irreducible $kG$-module with $kH$-submodule of dimension 1

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I have stumbled upon the following question :

Let $G$ be a finite group with a subgroup  $H$ and $k$ a field. Let $V$ be an irreducible $kG$-module of finite dimension with a $kH$-submodule of dimension 1. Show that $\dim(V)$ is less than or equal to $[G:H]$.

I know how to solve this if $k$ is the field of complex numbers using Frobenius' reciprocity but I  have no clue how to do it in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

You can write $G$ as the union of $g_1H,...g_nH$, suppose that the $1$ dimensional $H$-module is generated by $v$, since $V$ is irreducible, $\{gv,g\in G\}$ generates $V$, you can write $g=g_ih_i$ where $i=1,...,n, h_i\in H$, you have $(g_ih_i)(v)=g_i(v)$ this implies that $g_1v,...,g_nv$ generates $V$.

Comment: It's kind of nitpicking, but since $h_iv \in (kH)v = kv$, the element $h_i$ may not act on $v$ trivially, but as a scaler multiplication.